# Swap DOM nodes between two separate NodeLists

Tags: javascript, dom

Both `sampleItems` and `groupItems` have the same number of members.  How can I swap each of the nodes between the two lists, and keep them in the same order so that I can swap them a second time resulting in the original state.

```
var sampleItems = document.querySelectorAll('#form div.swap');
var groupItems = document.querySelectorAll('#groupby-inputs div');
console.log(sampleItems, groupItems)

document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="timeGroup"]')
.forEach(timeGroup => timeGroup.addEventListener('change', () => { 
        for(var i = 0, l = sampleItems.length; i < l; ++i) {
            //var sampleItem = sampleItems[i];
            console.log(i, sampleItems[i], groupItems[i])
            var groupItem = groupItems[i];
            var groupItemParent = groupItem.parentNode;
            var sampleItemsParent = sampleItems.parentNode;
            groupItemParent.insertBefore(sampleItems[i], groupItem[i]);
            sampleItemsParent.replaceChild(groupItem, sampleItems[i]);
            console.log(sampleItems, groupItems, groupItem, groupItems[i], groupItemParent)
            //groupItemParent.replaceChild(sampleItem);
        }
        console.log(sampleItems, groupItems, groupItem)

    }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely better solutions, but ended up using the following and it works.

```
var groupInputs = document.querySelectorAll('#groupby-inputs div');
var groupArray = [];
for(var i = 0, l = groupInputs.length; i < l; ++i) {
    groupArray.push(groupInputs[i]);
}
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="timeGroup"]')
.forEach(timeGroup => timeGroup.addEventListener('change', () => { 
    var sampleItems = document.querySelectorAll('#form div.swap');
        for(var i = 0, l = sampleItems.length; i < l; ++i) {
            groupArray[i] = sampleItems[i].parentNode.replaceChild(groupArray[i], sampleItems[i]);
        }
    }
));
```